# How to interrupt emacs when control-g does not work in very large files?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I've run into some kind of O(n^2) or worse behavior when viewing very large (e.g. 128MB) files in Emacs and jumping to the end of the file.  I think it may have to do with my coloring algorithm to color the text contextually.  If I type control-g (keyboard-quit), the operation is not affected.  I'd like some way to recover my emacs session without just killing it.  I tried sending a SIGINT, but emacs just exited.  Are there any signals I can send, or some other way (perhaps in a debugger) to force the whatever action is running to give up and return control to me?

Comment: I don't know of a way to make font locking interruptible, but you might find something of use in [this Emacs Wiki page on speeding up font locking](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontLockSpeed).

Comment: Did you try hitting escape 3 times ?

Comment: Yes, I think your own font-lock code is probably at fault here. Examine your `font-lock-keywords` regexps carefully to try to find the problem.

Comment: EMACS: Eight Megabytes And Constantly Swapping :-)

Comment: Hitting escape three times does nothing for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I doubt it's font lock mode.  That probably only does sections near what's visible.  It's probably copying data in memory.

> **`sigusr1`**
>
> **`sigusr2`**
>
> These events are generated when the Emacs process receives the signals `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`. They contain no additional data because signals do not carry additional information. They can be useful for debugging (see [Error Debugging](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html#Error-Debugging)).
>
> Source: [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual: Misc Events](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Misc-Events.html#index-user-signals)

I don't know what it would do (or what version of emacs you are running) but you could try a PROBABLY non-destructive signal (USR1 or USR2).

```
$ kill -USR1 pid
```

Or you could go to sleep and see if it recovers.

Comment: I wonder how busy (CPU and disk) your machine is.  That might tell you a little about what it's doing.  .. and you might be able to run another copy of emacs and "kill -USR1 pid" that new one to see what happens before you do the one you care about.

Comment: Wow, sending `kill -USR2` to [emacs-mac](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port) worked for me in a similar situation -- loaded a large file in js2-mode and started an isearch. USR2 quit the isearch and entered the debugger. Much better than killing the process!

Comment: I disagree with your doubts. The kill worked for me. It kicked me to the debugger and font-lock-default-fontify-region was where it was stuck.

Comment: I had to send the USR2 signal twice for some reason before really getting Emacs out of the rut it was in when I was editing Python code and failed to put `"""` before a method docstring. It really really should be more robust against silly problems like this.

Answer (score 4):

Here was my answer to a similar question which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47070702/3818556

---

So far the only way I found ever working is to send a `SIGUSR2` signal to the busy emacs process using command line `kill` -- no matter if it's running as a server (with `--daemon`) or not. This will not force terminating the emacs process while being able to interrupt what it's doing. Let's try an example to break a `sleep-for` loop running on emacs server. (Yes, `sleep-for` can be break by `C-g` but this is just an example. It worked on *some* cases when emacs does not respond to keyboard commands.)

First, start emacs server then use `emacsclient` connect to it, enter `M-: (sleep-for 120)`. Now go to another terminal and find the process ID of the server using command line: `ps x|grep 'emacs.*--daemon'`. Assuming the PID we found here is 12345. Now use the terminal to break it:

`kill -USR2 12345`

We should now see the `sleep-for` loop interrupted. On some cases I need to send this signal multiple times.

Also notice that `SIGUSR1` does not work so `SIGUSR2` is recommended, and this might only work on Emacs versions greater than v24. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I'm unaware of any signal handling that emacs does but you could use the Emacs Server by putting `server-start` in your ~/.emacs file so you can do RPC on your running instance of emacs.

Then when you want to kill emacs and write you can call from your shell `emacsclient -e '(save-buffers-kill-emacs t)'`.